# Extract the URL from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

Here in a csv file with differents links to jpg pictures : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rnsjn9D2mSrBULONpg1b1nw4ORu5aa8f/view?usp=sharing

Locally, I have done

```
import pandas

path = "/home/infinity/Downloads/"
path_1 = path + "fonds-de-la-guerre-14-18-extrait-de-la-base-memoire.csv"

df = pandas.read_csv(path_1)
```

In using that, I am not able to build a list of those links. How can I do that?

Comment: After reading the file, filter for rows that start with `https:` :   ``df[df["VIDEO-p"].str.startswith("https:")]``

Comment: This doesn't work because of NA values. The error is ```ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the following this. I guess you've already read your `csv`

```
                                                 VIDEO-p     Unnamed: 1
0      https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...            NaN
1                                       Positif original            NaN
2                                       Positif original            NaN
3      https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...            NaN
4                                         Front roumain    Personnalité
...                                                  ...            ...
18977                              Tirage photographique            NaN
18978  https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...            NaN
18979  https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...            NaN
18980                              Tirage photographique            NaN
18981                              Tirage photographique            NaN

[18982 rows x 2 columns]
```

Since, you're looking for all the row that contain the addresses `http://` you simply do this:

```
Liste_des_adresses = df[df["VIDEO-p"].str.contains("https://", na=False)]
```

which gives

```
                                                VIDEO-p Unnamed: 1
0      https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
3      https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
5      https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
6      https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
8      https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
...                                                  ...        ...
18972  https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
18973  https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
18975  https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
18978  https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN
18979  https://data.culture.gouv.fr/api/v2/catalog/da...        NaN

[10333 rows x 2 columns]
```

Et voilà!